# Appwrite PHP SDK Document Permissions: Setting Read and Write Access

Tags: php, appwrite

I want users to have specific permissions for documents in a collection:
All users should be able to read documents.
The document owner should be able to create, update, and delete their own documents.

I've tried setting up the permissions using the format like in the screenshot, but I think this is not the right format.
Can anybody give me a right example?

```
 $permissions = [
            Permission.read(Role.any()),                  // Anyone can read
            Permission.delete(Role.user($payload['owner'])), // Owner can delete
            Permission.update(Role.user($payload['owner'])), // Owner can update
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you would do:

```php
$permissions = [
    Permission::read(Role::any()),                  // Anyone can read
    Permission::delete(Role::user($payload['owner'])), // Owner can delete
    Permission::update(Role::user($payload['owner'])), // Owner can update
];
```

References:

- Playground for PHP: https://github.com/appwrite/playground-for-php/blob/4d4c52516602da7f74d0206d369112bd343f5f8d/playground.php#L85-L88
- SDK Source: https://github.com/appwrite/sdk-for-php/blob/461eedf4efd502dc905c3055f36f0e3583f67390/src/Appwrite/Permission.php#L7